# How to add a user to SQL server with Azure Active Domain

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I've been trying to added a couple of people as `readers` only to my Azure SQL server database. I've read multiple articles but for some reason none of the pieces of information I found gives me the answer.

I have added a Active Domain called `CTaC Information Systems` and when I got to [Azure](http://portal.azure.com) the to my sql server > settings > Users all it gives me the option to is import names from the Default Directory. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the directory that you (the currently signed-in user) are working in. Click your name at the top-right of https://portal.azure.com, and select the directory you'd like to use. Then you will see the users for that directory when you are assigning roles for various Azure resources.

Comment: Thank you this resolved my issue. Can't believe I didn't think of that.